# Dockerfile for the Elastic Beanstalk Web Server Environment offered for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

Can someone tell me if the Node.js platform that's available via the Elastic Beanstalk console when spinning up a new web server environment, is available somewhere as a Dockerfile? I'm having a world of trouble debugging my node api (even ssh-ing in and checking logs). Ideally I would like to download the Dockerfile that elastic beanstalk is using to run locally, but that doesn't seem to be available. So, if someone could point me in the right direction for available Dockerfile's for an eb web env that isn't dockerhub, (only found 2 on there, and they are the same mentioned in the aws docs) that would be great.

Comment: your question is a bit vague. can you elaborate on what is it you've done? What are you pushing to beanstalk when issuing `eb deploy`? Is it a dockerfile or a dockerrun.aws.json?

Comment: It's not a Dockerfile, that's what I want. Instead I provisioned the web service via the eb console. As far as I can tell there isn't a way to pull down the dockerfile (if there even is one).

Answer (score 0):

Beanstalk is not built with docker, so the answer to your question is no, you can't pull the Dockerfile or the image to play with locally. Beanstalk is basically a machine with Amazon Linux, wired up with some predefined scripts for Node.js (in your case). It will work only on AWS, not locally.
Now you didn't really write what is it you are having "a world of issues" with, but if Docker is something you're familiar with, you can build your own Dockerfile locally, and [provision it on Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html).

Comment: Thanks Tal. That's too bad that the pre-defined machines are not available as Dockerfiles. It would be a wonderful way to customize a tested environment. I'm going to just create a new Dockerfile with nginx defaults to try and mimic the eb provisioned web service environments. Do you happen to know if details about the node.js environment are available with more details than what is shown in the Software Configuration section in the console?

Comment: The best would be to just play with the provisioned machine. Amazon Linux setup is different than your docker container. care to share what issue you're facing?

Comment: Tal the issue I'm having is successfully running pm2 in cluster mode for my node api. I don't see any errors in the logs, and my env always stays Severe. I can run this just fine on digital ocean, and locally, but now in elastic beanstalk with the provisioned instances that eb sets up for me.

Comment: usually when this happens there's a clear error in one of the logs. make sure you cover them all (esp. eb-activity.log)

Comment: I've downloaded the full logs zip and browsed through each pretty carefully using os x's log viewer.